# How to get dynamically latitude and longitude on google maps?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have country and address.  How can I retrieve `latitude` and `longitude` from Google Maps V3?

I will use this to load the map.

**EDIT**

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/X5r8r/146/) is my actual code, but seems that Google API return this error : `W[B].bindTo=function(a,b,c,d){var c=c|...R[p](this,wf,a);this.Pb&&this.Pb(a)};`

**SOLUTION**
remove center: location,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retreive this with [Geocoding Requests](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding).

You can see my last project that I used this [here](http://www.plateformesinnovie.com/). See function `AddMarker` in `gmaps3.js` for a working real world example. Basically I fetch addresses from database (using AJAX) and then convert them to lat/lon to make markers on the map.

Comment: Tried. Check also my example, I get some errors and it doesnt works!

Comment: @markzzz Do you have an actual URL so we can see/debug the actual code?

Comment: Updated the link! Forgot to put #my_canvas as CSS style sheet ;) Still the same error anyway... :(

Answer (score 1):

You can use their ReST-API.

```
http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Berlin+Germany&sensor=false
```

The documentation is in [The Google Geocoding API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/). You will have to do a http request e.g. `$.get` in jQuery to perform the query and then parse the JSON. Other output formats include XML. There's a JavaScript geocoder on [their site](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding) as well.

Answer (score 1):

You need to access geocoding.

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/services.html#Geocoding

http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/geocoding/index.html